# Add IAM Authorization to API Gateway endpoint in CloudFormation yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I am looking at this example in this issue on the AWS SAM git project: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/25

```
swagger: "2.0"
basePath: "/Prod"
schemes:
  - "https"
paths:
  /report:
    get:
      responses: {}
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: "aws_proxy"
        uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<< account id >>:function:${stageVariables.LambdaFunctionName}/invocations"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
info:
  version: "1.0"
  title: "dev-reporting-test"
securityDefinitions:
  sigv4:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "Authorization"
    in: "header"
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: "awsSigv4"
```

I am trying to follow the same pattern, but I am not clear how this integrates with the rest of my SAM yaml file (CloudFormation template). I don't see any documentation on how to do this via the CloudFormation template SAM yaml file.

Any help would be appreciated.